# How to include operators in a php string for twitter advanced search?

Tags: php, search, variables, twitter

I want to do an advanced twitter search. Part of the code I'm using is listed below.

```
$q = "crazy monkeys"; // <This is the query string                 
$request = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=".urlencode($q);
```

The problem I have is that I want to search for the exact phrase "crazy monkey", but it is searching for tweets with crazy AND monkey in any order.

So what **I would like to** do is **include the " in my string.**

I thought I could do it by escaping the quote using `$q = "/"crazy monkey/"";`  but it didn't work.

If anyone could show me **how to include special operators such as " + or - in my twitter search**, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

The Twitter operators I am trying to use are listed here >   https://support.twitter.com/groups/31-twitter-basics/topics/110-search/articles/71577-how-to-use-advanced-twitter-search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The " and space are also handled well by urlencode

```
echo rawurlencode('"test with space "');
```

results in:

```
%22test%20with%20space%20%22
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

$q = "crazy monkey";

if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
$q=addslashes($q);

Answer (score 0):

you can use [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) also

```
$q = "crazy monkey";
echo http_build_query($q);
```

it will output as crazy+monkey